# How can I get the diff between two character variables in minutes

Tags: r, date, time

I have two variables that are both type "character". How can I get the diff between them in minutes:

```
  DisChargeDateTime      Visit_DateTime
  2012-01-12 15:40:48 2012-01-12 12:58:51
  2012-01-12 14:27:31 2012-01-12 13:14:17
```

I tried:

```
D$diff<-as.Date(as.character(D$DisChargeDateTime), format="%Y/%m/%d %HH:%MM:%SS") - as.Date(as.character(D$Visit_DateTime), format="%Y/%m/%d %HH:%MM:%SS")
```

but got diff `NA days`

Comment: Use `library(lubridate); library(dplyr)` and `df %>% mutate(difference=diff(minutes(ymd_hms(DisChargeDateTime)),minutes(ymd_hms(Visit_DateTime))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in base R using `difftime`:

```
D <- data.frame(DischargeDateTime = c('2012-01-12 15:40:48', ' 2012-01-12 14:27:31'),
                Visit_DateTime = c('2012-01-12 12:58:51', '2012-01-12 13:14:17'))

difftime(as.POSIXct(D$DischargeDateTime), as.POSIXct(D$Visit_DateTime), units = 'mins')
#Time differences in mins
#[1] 161.95000  73.23333
```

Comment: Thank you @LyzandeR

Comment: Hi @LyzandeR, an update: I tried the code on my own new data and it seems that  I get minutes diff of "o" or "1440" but in the data I should have got a variety of diffs . I guess something should be tuned?

Comment: Post a new question please, because it seems like a data problem (diff cannot be tuned since it doesn't really have any more arguments but you could check that your dates are of `POSIXct class`). Also, please use `dput` when uploading a data set so that we can see the actual data types (i.e. literally post the output of `dput(D)` in your question, or if the data is too big, only the part which demonstrates the problem).